# Extracting Security Logs With Python

Tags: python, events

I am running the below program which to my understanding should extract the date of successful logins and print the date of the successful logins. I am running this code in administrator mode, and while the code runs successfully, it does not print any log in dates.

```
import win32evtlog
import os

server = 'localhost'
logtype = 'Security' # 'Application' # 'Security'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)

while True:
    events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
if events:
    for event in events:
        if event.EventID == 4624:
            date = str(event.TimeGenerated)
            print(date)
```

My tasks is to print any successful login dates to a text file. should a statement such as this inside the event loop accomplish the task?

```
temp_file = open('temp.txt', 'a')
temp_file.write(date + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not printing any login dates (i.e. it is not working), writing to a file won't fix it. If you copied the code verbatim, the issue may be that the "if events:" block must be indented in the while loop. But yes, your statement , if placed in the while loop, would work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help, still learning the logic, syntax, and terminology. Ended up with this code which functions correctly, it was a simple indentation error and moving the write outside of the loop to get the output correct:

```
import win32evtlog
import os

logins = open('logins.txt', 'w')
logins.write('Login Attempts:' '\n')
server = 'localhost'
logtype = 'Security' # 'Application' # 'Security'
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)

while True:
    events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
    if events:
        for event in events:
            if event.EventID == 4624:
                date = str(event.TimeGenerated)
                print(date)
                logins.write(date + '\n')
```